# how to prompt a numpad in an iphone web app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, dashcode

I'm developing a web app for iphone using dashcode. I'm stuck where user needs to enter zip code or phone number and the app doesn't show the numpads but the regular keyboard.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. It used to be possible in iPhone OS 1 (it showed up for any `<input>` element with a ID that included 'zip' or 'phone), but OS 2/3 removed this functionality.

Comment: Adds complexity, but hardly a showstopper. The numpad functionality could definitely be duplicated with some HTML, CSS and JavaScript. It's just a bunch of buttons.

Comment: The regular keyboard allows users to enter numbers.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect @SimpleCode knows that. I suspect he's looking for a numpad UI for numeric-only entry.

Answer (score 3):

You can now as of iPhone 3.2-ish.
See: [iPhone UIWebview: How to force a numeric keyboard? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773843/iphone-uiwebview-how-to-force-a-numeric-keyboard-is-it-possible) - now with pictures!