# Input type only with numbers

Tags: javascript, iphone, input

I made a form that works only with numbers, and I want alert the user when he type letters which are invalid alert he and delete the caracther or make the input box red ..., how can I make that?

Comment: A form with an UIWebView ? with UITextView ? could you explain more please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773843

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone UIWebview: How to force a numeric keyboard?  Is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773843/iphone-uiwebview-how-to-force-a-numeric-keyboard-is-it-possible)

Comment: Don't "alert the user" with anything more than a red x or something, anything more intrusive than that will draw people away from your app

Answer (score 0):

Don't  let the user type anything else, if you dont want to.

You can observe the onkeypress-Event and check the charCode.
If it's not a Number, simply **return false**.